# How did someone stopped my wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, ip

hey i was just messing up with a guy on Kik who knows hacking. Suddenly there's no internet access on any of my connected devices for like 5 mins. Then when i got internet access. He kikked me claiming the hack. So, is my network not protected now? He was mentioning something about IPs. Should I be worried? There's a lot of data on my devices. **The guy is from a different country**

Comment: He didn't hack you.  Don't believe what people on Kik say.

Comment: how my internet stop? then

Comment: What he did to cause that isn't considering "hacking"

Comment: It's possible that some app has revealed your public IP and you experienced a DoS or DDos (Denial of Service). That person has prevented you from accessing the internet by filling your bandwidth, that's it.

Comment: should i be worried? about my DATA

Comment: A single person cannot perform a DDoS.  Which means at the very most it was a DoS attack.  **There is no possible for for this person to access the data on the device**

Comment: and as i know IP changes over time, so if i don't connect with that person he will not have my new IP, and he will not be able to perform that DoS attacks ? [last query :)]

Comment: My guess: He got your IP, tried to access your IP through browser, your router's web administration panel was accessible from WAN, and you didn't change it's default username and password.

Comment: haha guys, he asked me to click a link and then got my IP, am feeling so stupid, cant figure that out, now i came to know as i scrolled to see the past messages

Comment: You clicked on a link... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/can-you-get-virus-just-by-visiting-a-website-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

First, you were not likely compromised.  As the comments mention, he likely found your Global IP address, and then proceeded to send your modem/router more requests than it could handle (in other words, Denial of Service or Distributed Denial of Service attack).

As far as your data, that would depend on the firewall that is set up on your modem/firewall.  However, I wouldn't be too scared; even if he did interrupt your internet service for five minutes (which happens from time to time), that doesn't mean he gained access to your data.

As far as changing IP for security, your security provider likely has your modem on dynamic assignment.  Granted, your IP might not change for a month, unless you reset your modem.

Comment: i just reset the router, and when i google *my IP address* its changed, so i guess am protected :) thank you guys!

Comment: "Global IP address"....I think you mean public IP address.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I meant Global; different word, same thing.  It was the term I was taught in college to refer to any IP address that is visible to any internet accessible device.

Here, as an example:

http://www.myglobalip.com/

Comment: What you describe is a public address.

Comment: Like I said, they are both the same thing.  There is no difference between a global and a public address.

Comment: AT RAmhound, in your comment to the question, you  wrote  "A single person cannot perform a DDoS. Which means at the very most it was a DoS attack. "  <--- (you're not very convincing, since an individual could control multiple computers and push a button, but that aside),  This answer points out that it was likely a " Denial of Service or Distributed Denial of Service attack".  So why don't you retract your statement or say  that you are right and this answer is wrong.  Why take issue just with one term, when he flatly contradicted one of your claims.

Answer (score 0):

NOrmally global chat services are hosted by a server , so no simple user can see the other's IP address, but a malformed image or file transfer can cause the application to do unusual things, which I have seen on Paltalk.

I see no security threat other than nuicance disconnect.

If still concerned, inquire at lawenforcement@kik.com and report details of nuicance user.